# Telerik Reports - ReportController - SubReport

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

In `ReportController` override method -

```
public override HttpResponseMessage CreateInstance(string clientID, ClientReportSource reportSource)
```

`reportSource.Report` gives the required report file name - which is as expected.

However, when same method is called for a sub-report then `reportSource.Report`  returns complete server path of the sub-report rather than only the report file name.

Being new to Telerik, I am not sure if this is the default behaviour.
Is there any way I can change this to only receive the sub-report file name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per response from Telerik, this is the default behaviour for sub-reports.

It is logged as an issue and will be addressed in some future release of Telerik, more details here -
https://www.telerik.com/forums/reportcontroller---createinstance---clientreportsource#OSfgxHSV90eqefYeSlGUWg